# Aasorting in jQuery based on filters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a datatable style in which I want to disable/enable the initial sort based on some filters in aspx.
The setting has a aasorting property, lets assume I have a global variable "isDefaultSortingEnabled" and based on this variable I want to perform the sorting. I tried using if-else, but we cant write it inside the style setting.

```
                var objDataTableSettings = {
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "aaSorting": []  ,       // manipulate this sorting based on a global variable    
              //  "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']],
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary expression within the object to set the `aaSorting` property based on your global variable. Try this:

```
var objDataTableSettings = {
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bProcessing": true,
    'aaSorting': isDefaultSortingEnabled ? [] : [[ 1, 'asc' ]];
    // other settings...
}
```

If you prefer to use a full `if`/`else` statement, you would need to first create the object, then change the property as required:

```
var objDataTableSettings = {
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bProcessing": true,
    // other settings...
}

if (isDefaultSortingEnabled) {
    objDataTableSettings.aaSorting = [];
} else {
    objDataTableSettings.aaSorting = [[ 1, 'asc' ]];
}
```

The former is preferred due to its brevity.

Answer (score 1):

```html
if (isDefaultSortingEnabled) {
    aaSortingdData = [];
} else {
    aaSortingData = [[ 1, 'asc' ]];
}
var objDataTableSettings = {
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aaSorting": aaSortingData
}
```